# WordPress ImageFX Plugin - Not creating images for old posts

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to find a solution to a bug in an WordPress plugin now for awhile (I have not been able to get a response from the developer). The plugin is called [ImageFX](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imagefx/).

Basically it creates image effects for image uploaded into WordPress. I'm using it to turn images into grey scale. But if you create a page, save it and then later come back and try to add a featured image to it, that image will not get an ImageFX image created. You can see people having the [same problem here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-imagefx-doesnt-work-on-older-posts).

How to reproduce error:

1. Create a Page
2. Upload and set a featured thumb and publish page ( = ImageFX producers new thumbnail correctly)
3. Wait some time (I think 1 day). Then remove featured thumb and delete if from the gallery.
4. Upload new thumbnail ( = No new thumbnail created by ImageFX).

Alternatively, just try to upload an image to an old post/page. The ImageFX thumbnail will not be made.

My guess is this is the offending code. [You can see the whole file here](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/imagefx/tags/0.4/imagefx.php).

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'imagefx_filter' );
/**
 * Creates all ImageFX intermediate sizes of the image based on imagefx_options
 *
 * @param mixed $meta Metadata for attachment.
 * @return mixed $meta Modified metadata for attachment.
 */
function imagefx_filter( $meta ) {
global $imagefx_filters;

$options = get_option( 'imagefx_options' );

foreach ( $meta['sizes'] as $size => $info ) {

    if ( empty( $options['filter'][$size] ) ) continue;
    $filter = $options['filter'][$size];
    
    if ( empty( $imagefx_filters[$filter] ) ) continue;
    $callback = $imagefx_filters[$filter];
    
    $file = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = trailingslashit( $file['path'] ) . $info['file'];
    list( $orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type ) = @getimagesize( $file );
    
    if ( IMAGETYPE_JPEG === $orig_type || apply_filters( 'imagefx_image_type', false, $orig_type ) ) {
        
        $image = wp_load_image( $file );
        
        $callback( $image );
        
        $slug = $options['slug'][$size];
        if ( ! empty( $slug ) ) {
            $newfile = substr( $file, 0, -4 ) . '-' . $slug . substr( $file, -4 );
            $info['file'] = substr( $info['file'], 0, -4 ) . '-' . $slug . substr( $info['file'], -4 );
        } else {
            $newfile = $file;
        }
        
        if ( IMAGETYPE_JPEG == $orig_type )
            imagejpeg( $image, $newfile );
        
        do_action( 'imagefx_image_create', $image, $newfile, $orig_type );
        
        $meta['sizes'][$size]['file'] = $info['file'];
    }
    
}

return $meta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you ARE actually seeing a filtered image prior to having this issue? Are they in the media library for example?

If so, it isn't an issue with the plugin at all. You need set the filter to work on post-thumbnails (or whatever your featured image is calling). This way, your theme will be calling up the correct thumbnail.

Check the file name of the offending thumbnails, likely they'll differ from the 'correct' filtered image in the media library.

Comment: No, if you upload a new image to an old post, and set it as a featured thumbnail, the ImageFX image is not generated. But the regular image is uploaded and works. If you make a new post, and upload an image, the ImageFX image is created.

Comment: Just updated question with steps on how to reproduce the error.